# Problems using GPO from Windows Server 2000 to Windows 7

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, windows-xp, group-policy, windows-registry

So I'm using Windows Server 2000 (I know that's old and not effective but we are not in charge of the AD so no choice), and we don't have the access to GPO about users, only computers. That's why we use some scripts to make the work.

I'm using GPO to change a registry key value and to install some MSI. My problem is that it works great with XP, installation and reg file at startup, but it does not qork with Seven, nothing happend.

I'm not a pro with AD and GPO, if someone have an idea about what could be my problem source, I'm very interrested.

Answer (score 2):

Startup Scripts are processed the same way under Windows 7 as they are by Windows XP (run as SYSTEM, asynchronous by default, hidden by default).

My gut says your script is running. You could add a function to output a file into the %TEMP% folder to be sure.

Are these 64-bit Windows 7 clients and are you sure you shouldn't be modifying a WOW6432Node subkey?